# ansible does not load my host_vars/server-foo/public.yml file

Tags: ansible

i have this structure

```
hosts
host_vars/server-foo/public.yml
group_vars/staging/public.yml
```

and in the `hosts` file i have defined a group like this

```
[staging]
server-foo
```

Im trying to define a variable that will only be true for `server-foo`, so i add the line to the file `host_vars/server-foo/public.yml`

```
bar: true
```

When i try to run the playbook, im getting an error

```
fatal: [staging-accounts] => error while evaluating conditional: bar
```

If i add `bar: true` to `group_vars/staging/public.yml`, then the variable is picked up without any issues.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong ? I believe i have been following the ansible suggested method for defining host specific variables.

Comment: It might be that `host_vars/` needs to be relative to (in the same directory of) your `hosts` file. Do you have `$ANSIBLE_HOSTS` set to something local to your project?

Comment: i have `inventory = ./hosts` in my `~/.ansible.cfg` file and im running my playbook from the same directory as the one `hosts` files is in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure defined is correct in that `host_vars/<server>/public.yml` should be picked up. Ensure that the `<server>` folder name is the same as the server entry in the inventory file. For example if you have an IP address in the inventory, but a domain name as the folder name it will not work, they must match.

Comment: You save my day... The name of the host_vars file should the same of the name of the inventory line (and not the same of the inventory section name).